# PowerShell - regex for changing delimiter in multi-value field

Tags: regex, powershell, multivalue

I have a tab delimited data set as such (some columns removed but not relevant here):

```
XYZ 12345671    18884   18912   222.00  222.00  Standard    2   CMD.1
ABC 12345672    18875   397.00  Standard    1   CMD.2
ABC 12345673    18889   18919   18950   146.66  146.66  146.68  Standard    3   CMD.2
XYZ 12345674    18840   18871   18901   193.00  193.00  192.00  Standard    3   CMD.1
```

Unfortunately in the data set there are two multi-value fields (with 1 or more sub-values) using the same delimiter as every other column. All of the 5 digit numbers starting with 18 are one field, then all of the decimal numbers are a second field. The number of sub-values will always match between these fields (that is, if the first has 2 values the second will have 2 values). The lonae number by itself between "Standard" and "CMD.X" is the number of sub-values in each of those fields. Basically, what I'm trying to create is:

```
XYZ 12345671    18884;18912 222.00;222.00   Standard    2   CMD.1
ABC 12345672    18875   397.00  Standard    1   CMD.2
ABC 12345673    18889;18919;18950   146.66;146.66;146.68    Standard    3   CMD.2
XYZ 12345674    18840;18871;18901   193.00;193.00;192.00    Standard    3   CMD.1
```

Due to the filesize, I am trying to use this with System.IO.File (as many as 100,000k records):

```
$File = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('in_file.txt')
    ForEach($RecordSet In $File){
        $RecordSet = $RecordSet -CReplace '(?m)(/d/d/d/d/d)`t(/d/d/d/d/d)','(/d/d/d/d/d);(/d/d/d/d/d)'
        $RecordSet = $RecordSet -CReplace '(?m)([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)`t([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)','([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+);([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)'

    Add-Content ('out_file.txt") $RecordSet
}
```

Yes, I realize the in_file.txt is a stupid format -- it's not changeable unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1

Maybe,

```
(?<=\s\d{5}\b)\s+(?=\b\d{5}\b)|(?<=\s\d{3}\.\d{2}\b)\s+(?=\b\d{3}\.\d{2}\b)
```

and a replacement of `;` might be OK to look into.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/wp1tm9/1/)

### Method 2

or you can likely capture those with an expression similar to,

```
(\d+)\s{3}(\d+)\s{3}(?:(\d+)\s{3})?(\d+\.\d+)\s{2}(\d+\.\d+)\s{2}(?:(\d+\.\d+)\s{2})?Standard
```

then, replace with `$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;` or `$1;$2;$4;$5;`.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/E3VjGQ/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/E3VjGQ/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Nicely done; using method 1, it looks like this one-liner will do what Ryan wants: `(Get-Content in_file.txt) -replace '(?<=\s\d{5}\b)\s+(?=\b\d{5}\b)|(?<=\s\d{3}\.\d{2}\b)\s+(?=\b\d{3}\.\d{2}\b)', ';'`; pipe to a file by appending `... | Set-Content out_file.txt`

Comment: This will work with exception of replacing \s with \t -- the data is tab delimited.